# Draggable failing miserably in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9jSg/1/)

In this simple example, you should be able to drag the red box into the dashed area. It works in IE and in Chrome, but not in Firefox. What's really weird is that the `dragstart` event fires (causing the element to be hidden), and yet nothing else happens - not even the `dragend` (leaving it hidden and thereafter unusable).

```
var source = null;
document.getElementById('drag').addEventListener("dragstart",function(e) {
  source = this;
  e.dataTransfer.clearData();
  e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
  setTimeout(function() {source.style.visibility = "hidden";},1);
});
document.getElementById('drag').addEventListener("dragend",function(e) {
  this.style.visibility = "";
  source = null;
});
document.getElementById('drop').addEventListener("dragenter",function(e) {
  if( source) {
    if( e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
document.getElementById('drop').addEventListener("dragover",function(e) {
  if( source) {
    if( e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
document.getElementById('drop').addEventListener("drop",function(e) {
  if( source) {
    this.appendChild(source);
    source = null;
  }
});
```

I know this code isn't the most efficient (overuse of `getElementById` when I should just use it once, copy-pasted callback for `dragenter`/`dragover`), but it gets the point across.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

As per this article [here](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/wiki/Sorting-with-the-help-of-HTML5-Drag'n'Drop-API), i believe the issue was this line

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('Text',''); //you need this so that your code will work on Firefox.
```

Working perfectly in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9jSg/5/)

Comment: Ah, so that was it. I knew I must have been missing something, I didn't realise Firefox required at least some form of data to be set. It all makes sense now! Thank you!

Comment: link no longer works... and that fiddle doesn't work for me. Hmm!